# Angular 2 How to use google maps in multiple components

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I'm building Angular4 project that uses google maps api. I've built a component called basemap in which I've included the google api through jsonp (to get rid of cross origin error when using http module) as follows (basemap.component.ts):

```
if (typeof google === 'undefined') {
// google not available so go fetch it
 this.jsonp.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKEY&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`)
    .subscribe(res => {
     // google global object available here
    });
} else {
 //google was fetched before and google global object available here
}
```

and that works pretty good, but the problem when I use this component multiple times in the same page using ngFor

```
 <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">  <app-basemap ></app-basemap> </div>
```

I get the following error in the console 
`You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

I can't use this component [AGM - Angular Google Maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) because I'm using [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com) as the map visualizing api and google mutant plugin to view google base map.

Comment: How about <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]"><app-basemap </app-basemap></div> ?

Comment: @Vega that's actually what I'm using.

Comment: no, your version is <app-basemap *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]"></app-basemap>
it's not the same

Comment: that was to simplify the problem, any way I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ok, but you should always put the occurate code, plunkr is better

Answer (score 0):

for any one who come searching for the solution, I've managed to solve the problem using RXJS:
I've created a service google-api.service.ts in as the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleAPIService {
private googleReadyObservable;
constructor(
   private jsonp: Jsonp
) {
  this.googleReadyObservable = new Subject();
  this.jsonp
  .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`)
  .retry()
  .subscribe(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      this.googleReadyObservable.complete();
    }
  });
 };

googleReady() {
return this.googleReadyObservable;
  };
}
```

then in any component foo.component.ts import the service file then inject it in the constructor

```
constructor ( 
  private googleAPIService: GoogleAPIService
 ){  }
```

then use it in any function as following:

```
this.googleAPIService.googleReady()
    .subscribe(
  null,
  err => console.log(err),
  () => {
     // google maps global object loaded
  }
  );
```